# How to load one HTML page into another which has java script code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where the Spring based web application is returning a HTML based response.

Now, I want to embed this html response into another web page. The HTML response when rendered independently (meaning not in any other web page) works fine.

There is lot of JQuery related code in the response page which is not getting triggered when the response is loaded in another page.

How can I achieve this?

Since the response which is returned includes lot of JavaScript which has been written to make the UI responsive I have to make sure that all those libraries also load and function correctly.

I will list them below:
1. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)
2. [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) 
3. [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

I do not know how all these libraries function but yes they are definitely playing a key role in making the UI responsive.

I have also taken a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032767/insert-html-into-a-page-with-ajax) but could not understand whether this will satisfy my requirement.

Just to add I came across [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) but not really sure if it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Iframes, just give your iframe an id 'myIframe' and on getting html response, do the following from javascript:

document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.write("here is your html response..");

Hope this helps.